# Property [slug] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i got this error while trying to get to the page product-details using the slug 
which is already stored in my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAR7.png)

no this is the code in my index.blade.php

```
<div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail"><a class="ps-shoe__favorite" href="#"><i class="ps-icon-heart"></i></a><img src="{{ $product->image }}" alt=""><a class="ps-shoe__overlay" href="{{ route('products.show', $products->slug) }}"></a>
```

and this is the route

```
Route::get('/all/{slug}', 'ProductsController@show')->name('products.show');
```

this is the show function in my controller

```
 public function show($slug){

    $products = products::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('products.show')->with('products', $products);

}
```

***thank you in advance***

Comment: what about your index route and function? Can you add index route and function code in the question? It will help to answer your question.

Comment: Pls. provide your index function and it's routes.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `$products` to your blade, but use it as `$product->image`. I think this is your problem.

```
<div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail"><a class="ps-shoe__favorite" href="#"><i class="ps-icon-heart"></i></a><img src="{{ $products->image }}" alt=""><a class="ps-shoe__overlay" href="{{ route('products.show', $products->slug) }}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i am seeing here:

Replace From:

```
public function show($slug){

    $products = products::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('products.show')->with('products', $products);

}
```

Replace To:

```
public function show($slug){

    $products = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('products.show')->with('products', $products);

}
```

make sure you have used the CAPITAL "P" in products and also removed last "S" as we need to use plural form of model. also i think because of that you are not getting the data from the database.